# Javascript Binding to Div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating dynamically `div` tag. When I click on a link, I want to show on lightbox inside.

I already wrote a code like below, but something is gonna wrong when I click on a link to just show the last item.

```js
$(function () {
  $('td.job a').click(function () {
    $('.job_box').show();
  });
  $('.job_box .close').click(function () {
    $('.job_box').hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="click1" href="javascript:void(0)">Click One</a>
<a id="click2" href="javascript:void(1)">Click Two</a>

<div id="click1" class="job_box mem_login_box">
  <div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="close" title="close">close</a>
    <div class="m_title">Content</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="click2" class="job_box mem_login_box">
  <div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="close" title="close">close</a>
    <div class="m_title">Content</div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to make a Accordion. https://jqueryui.com/accordion/#collapsible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite somethings wrong... kindly try the following code and let me know if it works for you:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('.job a').click(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
            $("#"+id+"-div").show();
        });
        $('.job_box .close').click(function () {
            $(this).parent().parent().hide();
        });
    });
</script>
<div class="job">
<a id="click1" href="javascript:void(0)">Click One</a>
<a id="click2" href="javascript:void(1)">Click Two</a>
</div>
<div id="click1-div" class="job_box mem_login_box">
            <div>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="close" title="close">close</a>
                <div class="m_title">Content</div>

            </div>
        </div>
</div><div id="click2-div" class="job_box mem_login_box">
            <div>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="close" title="close">close</a>
                <div class="m_title">Content</div>

            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer this [`Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/xs9e6moL/59/)

**HTML**

```
<a divId="click1" class="open" href="#">Click One</a>
<a divId="click2" class="open" href="#">Click Two</a>

<div id="click1" class="job_box mem_login_box">
    <div>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="close" title="close">close</a>
        <div class="m_title">Content1</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="click2" class="job_box mem_login_box">
    <div>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="close" title="close">close</a>
        <div class="m_title">Content2</div>

    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function () {
        $('.open').click(function () {
            var parentDiv = $(this).attr("divId");
            $("#"+ parentDiv + " div").css("display", "block");
        });
        $('.job_box .close').click(function () {
            $(this).parent().hide();
        });
});
```

Comment: do you want to show the div when click on 'click one' and 'click two'?